# How to manipulate clock times (org-mode)

Tags: org-mode

I often forget either to clock out of a task, or to clock a different activity in.

For instance, I was working on a (clocked) task right now, then my manager walked in and we embarked on a discussion which lasted a good 40 minutes... So not negligible.

What is the best way to go about this? I would like - if possible - to subtract the time of this discussion from the main task I was working on, and add it to a new activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use `M-S-Up` and `M-S-Down` on the CLOCK line of a task then, in addition to adjusting that clock time, it will also adjust the clock entry of the previously clocked-in task.

Practically what this means is that, in your scenario, if you clock into your new task 40 minutes late, just adjust its start clocking time back 40 minutes with `M-S-Down` and it will also adjust the end time of the previous task so there's no overlap.

I use this all the time for exactly the scenario you describe.

Comment: Oh, that is even finer! Indeed, I used legoscia' suggestion, then adjusted the preceding clock accordingly. I will try your more thorough sugguestion. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't that be `M-S-Down` to move the clock backwards in time 40 minutes?

Comment: Eek, yes you're right. How could that stay wrong for nearly six years?! Corrected, and thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

One way to manipulate the time is to clock out, go to the clock entry, and change it with Shift-up and Shift-down.  If point is on the minutes, it will change by 5 minutes for each key press, and if point is on the hours, it will change by one hour for each key press.

Comment: While this does adjust the clock, it will cause an overlap with the previously clocked-in task, which is what the questioner was trying to avoid. I think my answer avoids that issue (additionally use the META key when bumping clocks up and down).